# Does the root server password have access to all mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple MySQL database
each database has different passwords
when updating table from one database to another ( I am making sure they all match )
does the root server password have access to all databases

for example

```
$query="CREATE TABLE ".$TableRow[0]." LIKE ".$dbname.".".$TableRow[0];
```

works on my wamp server
but when i try it on my VPS server online will root be the proper password?

I have written code that compares all the table and makes the mismatching tables between databases have the same values which works perfect on my localhost

Comment: Yes, root password or mysql root user has access to all databases.

Comment: On your VPS you have to manually add the user to the database that the user can access. Yes root has access to all, it's root.

Comment: Did you think of trying this for yourself before asking the question?

Comment: i was going to do it tonight when no users were on the system. Thanks for the answers I appreciate it.